# open path files to different iframes

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

```
<?php 

// directory path can be either absolute or relative 
$dirPath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/statistics/pdf/"; 

// open the specified directory and check if it's opened successfully 
if ($handle = opendir($dirPath)) { 

   // keep reading the directory entries 'til the end 
   $i=0; 
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
   $i++; 

      // just skip the reference to current and parent directory 
      if (eregi("\.pdf",$file)){ 
         if (is_dir("$dirPath/$file")) { 
            // found a directory, do something with it? 
            echo "<a href='$dirPath/$file' ><font color='black' link='black' vlink='black' > $file  </font></a><br>"; 
         } else { 
            // found an ordinary file 
            echo "<a href='$dirPath/$file' ><font color='black' link='black' vlink='black' >$i . $file  </font></a><br>"; 
         } 
      } 
   } 
   // ALWAYS remember to close what you opened 
   closedir($handle); 
}  
?>
<iframe src="xxx" width="100%" height="800"style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

I want to open every different file from my dir into iframe div, to hide the previous and show the pressed link. Those files I open it from my path and I want to have a list with those files and open it in iframe.

Comment: So what is the actual question? Welcome to SO, please visit the [help] to see how to ask

Comment: i have the code to open my div (to a link list),my list have 100files,
and i want to open it in to different iframe (i have the code of iframe)
but i dont know how take from the php to open it to a div and replace the other one

Answer (score 0):

You want to target the iFrames?

```
if (is_dir("$dirPath/$file")) { 
  // found a directory, do something with it? 
  echo "<a href='$dirPath/$file' target='iframe1'><font color='black' link='black' vlink='black' > $file  </font></a><br>"; 
} else { 
  // found an ordinary file 
  echo "<a href='$dirPath/$file' target='iframe2'><font color='black' link='black' vlink='black' >$i . $file  </font></a><br>"; 
}
```

using

```
<iframe name="iframe1" src="about:blank" width="100%" height="800"style="border: none;"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe2" src="about:blank" width="100%" height="800"style="border: none;"></iframe>
```